# eSELECTplus API integration issue

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate eSELECTplus (Moneris) with my application using PHP and I keep on running into weird error.

Everything works fine as long as I am using the test api key and store id. When I switch to live API key and store id i start getting "SQL Problem" from the server.. that's the response that I get back from the server.

Not sure what is causing this. Has anyone else ever run into this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Figured this out. Please close the question if needed.

Comment: Can you please post what was the fix, John? Seems like really long ago though.

Comment: @Obaid post what fix your problem??

Comment: It is 2017, and we are still facing same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone is still having this issue, Moneris is not that great.  It turns out the order of some of their xml request elements matter.  So if you have had to create your own api bc their api is terrible, make sure you put the store_id xml element before the api_token element.  Also, the host in the mpgGlobals class is defaulted to the test host, so once you go live you have to change 'MONERIS_HOST' from esplusqa.moneris.com to esplus.moneris.com

```
<request>
    <store_id>storeid</store_id>
    <api_token>apitoken</api_token>
    <us_purchase>...</us_purchase>
</request>
```

The above will work, the BELOW WILL NOT WORK

```
<request>
    <api_token>apitoken</api_token>
    <store_id>storeid</store_id>
    <us_purchase>...</us_purchase>
</request>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I've get the content request I send to server (XML) and verifyid each fields' data. I've checked if it matches data type specified in the documentation. I've found some values that haven't match the requirements and fixed them in my script. It maked my script work.

Answer (score 0):

It amazes me how terrible the available Moneris mpgClasses.php file is coded as well as how incomplete it is. I've had to make multiple changes to the class file to make it usable for both the Canada and US versions of the file, which is also ridiculous that there are 2 versions when the only real difference is field names. Without my fixes, the file just died with multiple php errors.

I've had the Canada version of the class working perfectly on my online store for over a year. Now I am trying to use the USA version of the Moneris API and it is a mess.
Even with my changes in place it is throwing this useless "SQL Problem".

Turns out it means your account is invalid or mistyped. I was using the test account "monusqa02" instead of "monusqa002" and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting SQL Error while trying to validate CC Number.
Tech support told me that this was because we did not have the **vault feature enabled** in our account.

> SQL Error - You need to add the Vault feature to your account.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the SQL Problem for me was caused by the downloaded mpgClasses file 
***vault version

where found

```
    MONERIS_HOST => 'esplus.moneris.com',
```

and should be

```
    MONERIS_HOST => 'esplusqa.moneris.com',
```

at least to get the 'testing' done for integration